# how to create a new variable in an individual-level data frame based on values from a state-level data frame?

Tags: r, loops, data-cleaning, multi-level

I am trying to create a new variable in a data frame (DF) that is based on data contained in another DF, where DF 1 is individual-level data and DF 2 is state-level data. To illustrate, here is a snapshot of DF 1:

```
(DF1 <- data.frame("id"=1:5, "s1"=c("MA", "MA", "RI", "NY", "VT")))

  id s1
1  1 MA
2  2 MA
3  3 RI
4  4 NY
5  5 VT
```

where ID = individual participant identifier and S1 = state of residence.

D2 looks like:

```
(DF2 <- data.frame("state"=c("MA", "RI", "NY", "VT"), "score"=1:4))

  state score
1    MA     1
2    RI     2
3    NY     3
4    VT     4
```

Where state is each of the US states and score is a value for an index measuring different aspects of inequality at the state-level. (In reality, DF2 has 51 rows).

I am trying to create a new variable in DF1 called s1_exposure that is equal to the score assigned to each state in DF2. I was trying something like this:

```
levels(DF1$s1)
states_s1 <- levels(DF1$s1)[1:4] # put state names in a list
DF1$s1_exposure <- 99
for(i in states_s1){
  DF1$s1_exposure[DF1$s1==i] <- DF2$score[which(DF2$state==i)]
}
```

But get this error:

```
Error in DF1$s1_exposure[DF1$s1 == i] <- DF2$score[which(DF2$state ==  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Any help would be appreciated! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a join

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
     left_join(D22, by = c('s1' = 'state'))
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. however, i am still confused as to how this would be able to create the variable that I am interested in creating. i don't need to merge the data, but rather create a new variable based on the second data frame.